# How to use real coordinates in leaflet CRS

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet

I have a shop map in SVG and I'm using image layer and CRS.Simple to show this SVG as a map. The problem is that the site will receive real user coordinates and my "virtual" map uses simple coordinates [[0,0],[1000,1000]].

[image: SVG Map]

[image: IRL place]

I know the irl coordinates of the corners, how do i get their relatives in the SVG map

Comment: What do you mean by "real user coordinates"? WGS84 latitude-longitude coordinates? Building-relative coordiantes in meters? They both are "real".

Comment: @IvanSanchez get the relative coordinates in the SVG map, from the coordinates that "navigator.geolocation" outputs

Comment: And you've got some points where you know both the WGS84 lat-lng coordinate and the SVG-relative coordinate, right?

Comment: @IvanSanchez right!

Comment: Then please edit your question to add that information, together with examples of how the SVG map looks like and where the control points are.

Comment: @IvanSanchez done